# MapView showing black screen

Tags: android

i am integrating google maps in my application. when i compile and rum my app on emulator it shows me black screen. i added the required permissions and add the `user-library` tag in the manifest but it still shows black screen. here is my code

```
public class ActivityLiveMap extends MapActivity {
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private Location location;
    private List<Overlay> overlayList;
    private GeoPoint mapPoint;
    private MapController controller;
    private MapView map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        map.setSatellite(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.locationmeter"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="5"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.LocationMeter" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.locationmeter.ActivitySplash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ActivityMenu" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ActivityCurrentLocation" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ActivityLiveMap"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

please help me, Thanks

Comment: have you got the app key?

Comment: Yes i got it the debug api key. when i first run the app it was displaying the tiles. but when i added an overlay , it started to display black screen. even after i remove all the code of adding overlay it still showing black screen

Comment: have you try clean and run project again?

Comment: Yes i did. but just now i created a new `avd` and run the app on this and this time it is showing me tiles. i have read other posts too. this happens due to internet pemission not added in manifest. but i have added it too. the problem was that some how internet was disable on my emulator and thats why mapview was not showing tiles.

Comment: ok now the proble is solved?

Comment: look like it is solved .working on my new emulator , but i tried the same app on my previous emulator it still shows my black tiles and internet is enable on this emulator now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you make sure that you have the :

```
- debug key
- internet permission
- internet enabled
```

Comment: i got the debug key and added the permission. but i think internet was not enabled on my emulator. i tried new emulator and now its working fine